# Update Column From A Query With Informations From A Query As Well PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way i can able to execute the 3rd query?
The selected columns where columns 6,7 and 8
The output of the second query are output1, output2 and output3
I want to update the selected columns with the informations from the second query

```
    $query=mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM table LIKE 'SELECTEDCOLUMNS%'");
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    $column=$result[0];
    echo $column;
    }

    $query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE <MY_CONDITIONS>");
    while($result1=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
    {
    $grade=$result1[0];
    echo ('<input type=text value="$grade" name="have no idea what to put here">');
    }

    $query2=mysql_query("UPDATE table SET `$column`='name of textbox'");
```

here's my code, what i have done so far

```
    <?php
    $a=mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM 1st_year_1st_sem WHERE Field NOT IN ('USERNAME',
    'STUDENTNUMBER', 'STUDENTNAME', 'SUBJECTS', 'UNITS')");
    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
    {
    echo('
        <input type=text value="'.$b['0'].'" name=subjects>
        ');
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    $aa=mysql_query("select * from 1st_year_1st_sem where STUDENTNUMBER=$studentnumber");
    while($bb=mysql_fetch_array($aa, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
    for ($count=5; $count < count($bb); $count++)
    {
    <form action="save.php" method=POST>
    $grades=$bb[$count];
    echo ('<input type=text value="'.$grades.'" style="width:75; text-align:center"
    name=grade>');
    }
    </form>
    }
```

save.php

```
    $grade=$_POST['grade'];

    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
    $a=mysql_query("UPDATE 1st_year_1st_sem SET $b='$grade' WHERE
    STUDENTNUMBER='$studentnumber' ") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

anyone here who can help me with my problem?

Comment: Try putting `$query2=mysql_query("UPDATE table SET `$column`='$grade'");` after `echo $grade;` (inside the loop). Also check for errors by adding `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`

Comment: i'm sorry but i forgot to add something on my code i have placed the value of $grade in a textbox so that it can be edited and the value of the textbox will be the one that will be replaced to the current informations. i will edit my question as well

Comment: Add `$input = $_POST['input_name'];` then modify as 
`<input type="text" value="$grade" name="input_name">` - make sure you do have form tags with a `method="post"` if you're not already doing so. Then do `SET $column='$input'` - Try that and see if it will work.

Comment: One step at a time. Did my suggestion work? Edit: You deleted your comment.

Comment: as for 2nd query there will be 3 textboxes that have values 1, 2 and 3 i tried changing all the values but it seems that the last one was just the one being replaced

Comment: You're going to have to show me more code, if not full code if there isn't too much of it.

Comment: @Fred -ii- i have posted my codes on my question any idea? thanks